# How do I bypass a circular import?

Tags: python, import

I have a python file with all the functions I want to use, while I have another one for my main code.
We'll call the function one "functions.py" and the main one "main.py".

The functions in my functions.py file require variables from the main.py file. When I try to import one to another I get a circular import error.

Example:

main.py:

```
from functions import func
variable = 10

func()
```

functions.py:

```
from main import variable
def func():
    variable += 1
```

Now I want variable to be 11.

I understand why this happens but is there any way to make this work?

Sorry for my rookie questions, and thank you in advance.

Comment: The lazy fix is to move the import statement  inside the function. The correct solution is to re-think the structure of the code.

Comment: "The functions in my functions.py file require variables from the main.py file" - bad idea. Consider restructuring your program to use arguments, return values, and possibly classes and instances.

Comment: Also, even without the circular import problem, `variable += 1` wouldn't affect the main `variable`, for 3 separate reasons. Reason 1: `variable` will be treated as a local. Reason 2: even if you added `global variable`, you'd be setting `functions.variable`, which is a separate variable from `main.variable`. Reason 3: you've actually got 3 copies of `variable`, specifically `main.variable`, `functions.variable`, and `__main__.variable`, where `__main__.variable` exists due to Python's weird treatment of the main script file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @user2357112supportsMonica ! I will be taking your advice and working on it. Thank you again!

Comment: Move `variable` to `functions.py`

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to just pass the variable as an argument to your function. E.g.:

main.py:

```
from functions import func
variable = 10

variable = func(variable)
```

functions.py:

```
def func(variable):
    variable += 1
    return variable
```

Even if you *could* import it, or if you just moved `func` into the `main.py` file, Python would throw an `UnboundLocalError` complaining that `variable` is used before it's assigned since the `variable` in `func` is not the same as the `variable` outside of `func`. E.g.:

```
>>> v = 10  # outer v
>>> def func():
    v += 1 # inner v

>>> func()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    func()
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 2, in func
    v += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'v' referenced before assignment
>>>
```

Here, "outer v" is in the global scope, while "inner v" is in `func`'s scope, so they do not reference the same variable. For further reading, I'd encourage you to look up how scopes work in Python.